# методы split('') join('') как убрать "лишние"(мусорные) пробелы и откуда они вообще берутся?

Tags: javascript, консоль, join, split

Как бороться с появляющимися пробелами после использования:

```
split('').reverse().join('')
```

Хочется, чтобы функция осталась универсальной для строк и цифр:

```
function isPalindrom(checkArr) {
    console.log(checkArr);
    let insArr = checkArr.toLocaleString().split('').reverse().join('');
    console.log(insArr);
    return checkArr.toLocaleString() === insArr;
}
```

Вот результаты:

```
isPalindrom(11111);
11111
111 11
false
isPalindrom('11111');
11111
11111
true
isPalindrom('11121');
11121
12111
false
```

Comment: используйте вместо toLocaleString(). метод toString().

Comment: сработало, спасибо. Откуда все-таки берутся там пробелы не подскажете?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

Answer (score 1, accepted):

______ Для разнообразия _____

```
function isPalindrom(_checkArr) {
    console.log("_checkArr" + " = " +typeof(_checkArr) + " " +_checkArr);   
    var insArr = {"string": String,"number": parseInt}[typeof(_checkArr)](_checkArr.toString().split('').reverse().join(''))        
    console.log("insArr" + " = " + typeof(insArr) + " " +insArr);   
    return _checkArr === insArr;
}

console.log(isPalindrom(11111));
//checkArr = number 11111
//insArr = number 11111
//true
console.log(isPalindrom('11011'));
//checkArr = string 11011
//insArr = string 11011
//true
console.log(isPalindrom(11121));
//checkArr = number 11121
//insArr = number 12111
//false
console.log(isPalindrom('11cb21'));
//checkArr = string 11cb21
//insArr = string 12bc11
//false
```

Comment: L11VADIS: используйте вместо toLocaleString(). метод toString(). xalex: сработало, спасибо. Откуда все-таки берутся там пробелы не подскажете?

Answer (score 2):

Метод [`.toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toLocaleString) в случае с цифрами будет добавлять разделители групп

```js
console.log(11111..toLocaleString());
```

Как следствие разворачивается полученная строка, а не исходное число.

Чтобы это избежать можно использовать обычный `toString`, он переводит число в строку без дополнительного форматирования.